in Relational database, will index accelerator query: select count(*) from table where score >= number

Let's say we use MySQL
With 100 million records
Table schema: userid(pk), score
score ranges from 0 to 10^6
score has duplicates

So the question is when adding a index on score, will it accelerate this query:
select count(*) from table where score >= number

Why or why not? If not, are there any possible ways to accelerate this query?

Have you tested it? What was the result?

will it accelerator query Depends of the percent of the rows to be deleted. If it is above (approximately) 5% then the index won't improve. If it is above ~7-10% then the server won't use this index at all because its usage will degrade the performance.

An index might improve this query, as long as the values of score are a suitably good discriminator ("way of picking out rows").
If you have 99.9M rows with a score of zero and 100K with a score of 100, then score is not a very good discriminator, even if you only wanted rows with a score of 100.  MySQL has to be generic and consider how it could find any value using an index and, if there's a poor mix of values, the index won't help.
The better distributed the values are, the better the index becomes.
Of course, the extreme case of this is the Primary Key, which is unique to each and every record and, therefore, a brilliant discriminator.
Duplicate values don't really matter much.
MySQL can scan through an Index finding all the related records - assuming that the fields in the index are in the right order.  For example, finding users with a given score using a composite index on {userid,score} wouldn't work, but using one on {score,userid} would because all the index entries for a given score would appear together and MySQL can "loop" through them.

select count(*) from table where score >= number

will always use INDEX(score) -- Because the query can be done entirely in the index ("covering").  How much faster will it run?  That depends almost entirely on what percentage of the index needs to be scanned.  (Dup values don't matter.)  If the table truly has only 2 columns, then this index will also have 2 columns -- effectively INDEX(score, userid).  But only the "rows" in the index after "number" will be scanned to get the "count".
select * from table where score >= number

may or may not benefit from such an index, depending on number of columns, distribution of values, number, etc.
(The other answers go into details that are mostly irrelevant to the Question at hand.)

To add on top of Phill’s answer above/below, we could add that the way MySQL checks the cardinality of the index (how many different distinct values are stored in the column) is somewhat peculiar. As you can imagine, to check how many distinct values are in the column you would expect that the column is accessed and checked. It does not work that way. Instead, a (quite small) sample is used to get the data and analyse it. InnoDB can store index statistics in runtime or it can persist them (default setting).
In the first case, it will open randomly 8 pages from the table (8x16KB of data). In the second - 20 pages (20x16KB of data). This is the balance between having any idea what is in the table and I/O access that would have been required to open more data for analysis. You can manage this via variables. innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages for runtime stats and innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages for the persistent statistics. You can also do it on per-table level:
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
`id` int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`data` varchar(255),
`date` datetime,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
INDEX `DATE_IX` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB,
  STATS_PERSISTENT=1,
  STATS_AUTO_RECALC=1,
  STATS_SAMPLE_PAGES=25;

So, here we have table t1 where 25 pages will be used for statistics. This example is straight from MySQL documentation.
To sum up, if you know that the table has quite good cardinality and MySQL does not agree with you, preferring table scans over using index, there are couple of knobs you can tinker with to get the optimizer to do what you want (and without going into the area of optimizer hints like FORCE INDEX and similar).
